# Binding visibility property

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-phone, visibility

I have gone through several questions regarding this but couldn't get proper answer. I dont know where am wrong with the following code. I am binding visibility property of TextBlock but its not working. Here is my xaml code and am changing visibility property of textblock in button click.

```
<TextBlock Visibility="{Binding IsVisible}" Text="Visibility Sample" Margin="12,40" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="visibilityTextblock"/>
<Button Content="visibility" Tap="Button_Tap_1"/>
```

Here is my `Button_Tap_1` function.

```
private void Button_Tap_1(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
            IsVisible = Visibility.Visible;            
    }
```

Here is my `IsVisible` Property.

```
private Visibility _isVisible;
public Visibility IsVisible
    {
        get
        {
            return _isVisible;
        }
        set
        {
            _isVisible = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("IsVisible");                
        }
    }
```

And finally here is my `NotifyPropertyChanged` Method.

```
#region NotifyPropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string p)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged == null)
            return;
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));
    }

#endregion
```

By default, am initializing Textblock visibility to collapsed by changing its property like,

```
IsVisible = Visibility.Collapsed; ( in the constructor)
```

I also derieved from `INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface and am implementing all these in a same class file. Can anyone help me where am wrong?

Comment: Your code works for me, make sure your binding works (did you defined the datacontext of the windows ?). (Ex : try to bind a string to the text property of your textbox)

Comment: What is `DataContext` of your `TextBox`? (try to set `Text="{Binding}"` to see)

Comment: @Antoine and har07, As you people said, binding a string to the text property of the textblock works fine. But i could not change the text property at run time. For eg, am assigning another string for that property on button click and it does not change. Is there any problem with NotifyPropertyChanged? On keeping breakpoints, I can see PropertyChanged value is still null after button click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing your answer i'm almost sure you didn't implemented INotifyPropertyChanged well. So here is an exemple based on your problem (that works =) ):

**Windows : XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication7.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Visibility="{Binding IsVisible}" Text="Visibility Sample" Margin="12,40" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="visibilityTextblock"/>
        <Button Content="Button" Name="boutontest" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="216,247,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="74"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Windows : CS**

```
namespace WpfApplication7
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Logique d'interaction pour MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DataContext = new MainViewModel(this);
        }
    }
}
```

**Datacontext :**

```
namespace WpfApplication7
{
    class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private MainWindow mainWindow;

        private Visibility _isVisible = Visibility.Collapsed;
        public Visibility IsVisible
        {
            get
            {
                return _isVisible;
            }
            set
            {
                _isVisible = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsVisible");
            }
        }

        public MainViewModel(MainWindow mainWindow)
        {
            this.mainWindow = mainWindow;

            mainWindow.boutontest.Click += BoutonClick;
        }

        private void BoutonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            IsVisible = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }
}
```

**Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged**

```
namespace WpfApplication7
{
    public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are perfect. Its working fine but can you explain it more clearly, why my code didn't works?

Comment: Did you forget to add " : INotifyPropertyChanged" after your class name ?

Comment: Yep I added. But am deriving my New() Page from two base class, one is INotifyPropertyChanged. Like this,
New : PhoneApplicationPage, INotifyPropertyChanged